# Why we need crossCheckMatching for feature?

Tags: c++, opencv, sift, surf

I am reading lot of post for object detection using feature extraction (sift ecc).

After having calculate descriptors on both images, to get good matches they are using crossCheckMatching.  (found on [sample/cpp/descritpor_extractor_matcher.cpp](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp?rev=3943))

Coudl I understand why this choice?

Why we need to evalute both

```
descriptorMatcher->knnMatch( descriptors1, descriptors2, matches12, knn );
descriptorMatcher->knnMatch( descriptors2, descriptors1, matches21, knn );
```

I don't understand it.

Computing the Euclian distance for example doesn't return **the same result** in both direction ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't generally assume that the Eucludian distance will be used by your matcher. For instance, the BFMatcher supports different norms : L1, L2, Hamming...

You can check the documentation here for more details : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html

Anyway, all these distance measures are symmetric and it doesn't matter which one you use to answer your question.

And the answer is : calling `knnMatch(A,B)` is not the same as calling `knnMatch(B,A)`.

If you don't trust me, I'll try to give you a graphical and intuitive explanation. I assume for the sake of simplicity that `knn==1`, so that for each queried descriptor, the algorithm will only find 1 correspondence (much easier to plot :-)

I randomly picked few 2D samples and created two data-sets (red & green). In the first plot, the greens are in the query data-set, meaning that for each green point, we try to find the closest red point (each arrow represents a correspondence).

In the second plot, the query & train data-sets has been swapped.

Finally, I also plotted the result of the `crossCheckMatching()` function which only conserve the bi-directional matches.

[image: Figure 1]

And as you can see, the `crossCheckMatching()`'s output is much better than each single knnMatch(X,Y) / knnMatch(Y,X) since only the strongest correspondence have been kept.

Comment: Frederic first of all thanks for the great answer! But, consider we are using BruteForceMatcher, so basically each descriptor got compared with every other descriptors, at that point doing `knnMatch(A,B)` should be **the same** of `knnMatch(B,A)` don't you find ?

Comment: Also let's say they return different results. But to keep only the good match instead to run again a knnMatch couldn't be much better and faster to run a simple ratioTest on the matches?

Comment: According to the documentation, for each queried descriptor  BruteForceMatcher finds the closest one in the training set. I see no difference with the special case "knn==1" I've used in my answer.

Comment: For your second question, I've just noticed that the BFMatcher (not the same as BruteForceMatcher) constructor takes a "crossCheck" boolean parameter. It seems to be a built-in version of crossCheckMatching(). Take a look at : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html

Comment: Wow that explains a lot. Quoting: `If it is false, this is will be default BFMatcher behaviour when it finds the k nearest neighbors for each query descriptor. If crossCheck==true, then the knnMatch() method with k=1 will only return pairs (i,j) such that for i-th query descriptor the j-th descriptor in the matcher’s collection is the nearest and vice versa, i.e. the BFMathcher will only return consistent pairs. Such technique usually produces best results with minimal number of outliers when there are enough matches. This is alternative to the ratio test, used by D. Lowe in SIFT paper.`

Comment: Also just for curiosity: which software have you used for making that plot ? :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't dealt with the exact module you're using, but from the documentation:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html

It seems that the second call is swapping the training with the query, and hence can give you a different set of results. This is also hinted at by the naming of matches12 changing to matches21 -- it's not two-way association, but a direction association.

You see this in training large datasets in machine learning where you're results training one subset of the data gives a better performance than training on a different subset of the data. I don't know how the two matches are used after the step you've written but I imagine it allows for either choice of best training, or for capturing better covariance information from the data.

Euclidean distance is the same in both directions, but the ordering of the double vector changes and hence the structure of association changes between the two calls (unless descriptors1 == descriptors2, which would form a symmetric matrix and then probably be useless to repeat).

Posting the uses of matches12 and matches21 later in the codebase would probably also clarify the exact reason for having both direction associations.

Hopefully this gives a starting place for understanding the repeated call.

*** *EDIT* ***

I looked over the source code you provided a link to and in answer to your question, the distance IS the same between two points, but the closest point of a specific point (point A) to another particular point (point B) is not necessarily an invert-able statement. Thus B may be the closest point to A, but A may not be the closest point to B.

As Frédéric's post shows graphically, it's not that the Euclidean distance changes between 2 points but rather that the point with the closest Euclidean distance can change when changing the perspective of the comparison. Thus cross-checking can validate point which share closest point relationships (A is closest to B and B is closest to A).

Your intuition that this is not the best approach (with large numbers of points) is correct though, as a more complicated approach could find all such relationships in O(N*ln(N)) time instead of O(N^2) time -- especially a heuristic driven search. But for a (relatively) small number of points the expected performance gain would be negligible and the implementation would be (much for good improvement) more complicated.

Comment: i give you +1, but as you can understand this doens't answer my question

Comment: And I have updated the link in my answer to get the full code  https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/descriptor_extractor_matcher.cpp?rev=3943

Comment: Thanks for the +1 and the source code, hopefully my edits answers the original question for you.